# NSImageRep wrong resolution?

Tags: objective-c, size, tiff, nsimage, nsimagerep

MacOS 10.7.4 comes with new icons having image reps at 144 DPI. The bad thing is that when I load one of these icons in a NSImage I only get reps having a size of 512px. I mean: I load a 1024px/144dpi icns file in a NSImage and then I ask every image rep for its size... no rep has a size of 1024px, I only get sizes with a max. of 512px (no matter if a rep has a resolution of 72dpi rather than 144dpi: in fact new icons in 10.7.4, like TextEdit or Automator, have reps for both resolutions for each size except for 1024px which exists in a single rep at 144dpi).

Whay does NSImageRep seem like it doesn't understand its real resolution? Why do I get this issue just for 1024px/144dpi and not, for example, for 512px/144dpi?

If I read the TIFFRepresentation of the NSImage and I write it back to a file I get a correct 1024px/144dpi TIFF file, while if I write the same NSImage going through CGImageSource/CGImageDestination as kUTTypeTIFF I get a 1024px/72dpi file.

All these things are making me getting very confused.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs for `-[NSImageRep size]` say:

> The size of the image representation, **measured in points in the user coordinate space**.

(Emphasis added.)

This is not a measurement in pixels. It's a measurement in points, so an image that is 1024 *pixels* at 144 dpi measures 512 *points* when the points are 72 dpi.

You want to query the `-pixelsWide` and `-pixelsHigh` methods (if, indeed, you care about the pixel dimensions; often you should not).